# SQL : Select records at a time

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have question that at a time in select query how many records are selected that means what is maximum limit of selecting recods in sql 2K,2k5,2k8.

Thanks in advaces.

Comment: why do you think there exists such limit? it can break your businnes logic. imagine, you're asking db to retrieve all records with some condition, and it returns not all of data. it's rather the question of correct db-design imho.

Answer (score 3):

There's no hard limit that I'm aware of on SQL server's side on how many rows you can SELECT. If you could INSERT them all you can read them all out at the same time. 
However, if you select millions of rows at the time, you may experience issues like your client running out of memory or your connection timing out before being able to transmit all the data you SELECTed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is a built in 'limit' for selecting rows, it'll be down to the architecture that SQL server is running out (i.e. 32bit/64bit, memory available etc) Certainly you can select hundreds of thousands of rows without issue.

But... if you ever find yourself asking for that many rows from a database you should optimise your code / stored procedures so that you only retrieve a subset at a time.

Answer (score 0):

As @paolo says, there is no SQL-defined hard limit; you can specify a limit in your query with the LIMIT keyword (although that is database-dependent).

However, there is one important point: performing a SELECT query with actual database servers typically does **not** actually transfer the data from the server to the client, or load everything into memory. A query usually has a cursor into a resultset, and as the client iterates through the resultset more rows are fetch from the server, usually in chunks. So unless a client explicitly copies all data from the resultset to memory, at no point will this implicitly happen.

This is all completely database-dependent, and in many cases drivers allow tweaking of chunk size etc.